# Change where 0 degrees rotation is?

Tags: c#, wpf, angle, direction, degrees

I have a canvas with some objects on it, and I can rotate them based on some number entered where 0 is upward on the screen, 90 is to the right, 180 downward, and 270 to the left. Is there anyway to change where the 0 degrees is? Right now I'm assuming the canvas background image has north as straight ahead (it's a map), but if I have an image where 0 degrees north is to the left, I can't rotate my objects properly unless I can change where the original 0 degrees is. I was thinking I could have the user select where 0 degrees is, but it doesn't seem like I can retrieve the necessary information just by the user selecting a point. Any ideas?

Example: I have a map. 0 degrees is to the left (where 270 would be). The user knows this, but the program doesn't. Program thinks 0 degrees is still north. So if the user wanted to display his heading, he would have to add the offset of the two 0 degrees to his heading. Not sure how to get that offset though.

1st idea: I'm thinking if I get the center point of the canvas, and have the user click a point where 0 is, and get the angle the center point WOULD have to rotate to in order to be facing the new 0.

Comment: Add a RotateTransform to the Canvas?

Comment: " but it doesn't seem like I can retrieve the necessary information just by the user selecting a point." why? if you have an 'offset' for the rotation, just as you suggested, it should do the trick

Comment: I'd try to go from something like `Rotate(degrees)` to `Rotate(degrees, offset)`

Comment: How is it possible to get that offset in the first place though? I don't want to rotate the entire canvas, the image should stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

if you have viewmodel, then bind it to computed property:

XAML:

```
<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding FinalRotationAngle}" />
```

C#:

```
private double _northOrientationAngle;
private double _mapRotationAngle;


public double MapRotationAngle
{
    get { return _mapRotationAngle; }
    set
    {
        _mapRotationAngle= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MapRotationAngle");
        OnPropertyChanged("FinalRotationAngle");
    }
}

public double NorthOrientationAngle
{
    get { return _northOrientationAngle; }
    set
    {
        _northOrientationAngle= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NorthOrientationAngle");
        OnPropertyChanged("FinalRotationAngle");
    }
}

public double FinalRotationAngle
{
    get { return NorthOrientationAngle + MapRotationAngle; }
}
```

Now you have configurable north orientation as well as user defined orientation.

if you have custom control witout mvvm you can achieve the same using DependecyProperties and PropertyChanged callback

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
private double neutralPosition;

public void SetNeutralPosition(double position)
{
    this.neutralPosition = position;
}

public double Rotate(double angle)
{
    return this.neutralPosition + angle;
}
```

So the idea is: you use `SetNeutralPosition` to set where your "0" is relative to the REAL 0 degrees position. Then you can use the `Rotate` method (with your relative degree of rotation) to get the "real" rotation.

Comment: But how would I be able to actually set where the relative 0 is? I have the formula down to get the offset and then rotate everything based on that, it's just getting that relative 0 in the first place.